# Accessing entries of multidimensional variables using the gams-c++ api

Tags: c++, gams-math

I am generating the following gams program with my c++ program

```
variable x(*) /1.lo = -1,1.up = 1,2.lo = -1,2.up = 1/;
variable obj; equation eqobj; eqobj.. obj =e= x['1']+x['2'];
parameter ms, ss, lbd, ubd, cpu;
model mod /all/;
option decimals = 8;
solve mod minimizing obj using minlp;
lbd=mod.objest; ubd=obj.l;
ms=mod.modelstat; ss=mod.solvestat; cpu=mod.resusd;
```

and using the gams-c++ api to let gams solve it. Afterwards, I want to obtain the results in c++ using this method:

```
auto value = m_job.outDB().getVariable(var).findRecord().level();
```

were `job` is my `GAMSJob`, which was used to solve the program above and `var` is a string containing the variable name, whose value I want to obtain.
This methods works perfectly with one dimensional variables, e.g. when my variable looks as follows

```
variable x;
x.up = 1;
x.lo = 0;
```

and I am passing `"x"` as var in the code above.

I have tried to access the entries of the multidimensional variables now with a string like `"x['1']"`, but then always 0 is returned. What is the correct way to obtain the values I want, i.e. the entries of the multidimensional variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to iterate over all records of `x`? There is actually an example in the [tutorial](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_CPP_TUTORIAL.html#CPP_GETTING_STARTED) for a two dimension variable doing this:

```
for (GAMSVariableRecord rec : m_job.outDB().getVariable("x"))
    cout << "x(" << rec.key(0) << "," << rec.key(1) << "):" << " level=" << rec.level() << " marginal=" << rec.marginal() << endl;
```